# PHP: suddenly can't parse some word

Tags: php, arrays

```
$team = trim(split("are", $string)[0]); // Line 215
```

this code has syntax error but i can't solve this :(

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/zz.php on line 215

and When I define varible like this

```
$array = [
      "a",
      "b",
];
```

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

too

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: version is PHP 5.2.17

Comment: $team = trim(split("are", $string)[0]); code is working some times ago but suddenly don't work :(

Comment: You can't define arrays using square brackets prior to PHP 5.4

Comment: `split` is also deprecated in 5.3 and removed as of PHP 7. Use `explode`